# Why there's no history in Powershell when I connect to Windows with SSH?

Tags: powershell, ssh, history

When I connect to my Windows PC (home edition) with SSH, I'm in a Powershell session but each time I disconnect and reconnect, all my cli history is lost.
(Yes I'm connecting from a Ubuntu machine onto my Windows 10 computer with SSH).